# Logout on all browsers/devices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My Rails 3 app uses Devise for authentication, sessions are stored in cookie files. I'd like to have a feature of logging a user out on all browsers/devises simultaneously. Can this be done, or I have to store sessions in databases?

Answer (score 1):

As a quick solution, you can store a value named `should_logout` in user model, when logging out you should make `should_logout = true`

then in Application controller you can define `before_filter` where you can check for that  value if it's true

```
before_filter :check_should_logout
def check_should_logout
  if current_user.should_logout
      current_user.should_logout = false
      logout(current_user)
  end
end
```